# Classes that do not map to any domain entity

Tags: oop

In OOP, what is the name of the process that turns something that is not explicitly an entity in the application domain into a class? I had that word, but I forgot it and google is not helping. For example, the Strategy in the "Strategy pattern", that doesn't immediately seem to be a class

Comment: Anything here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms

Comment: nope, didnt find it there!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I still have to remember the source of this knowledge, but here it is
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)